BigBlueButton hidden public_chat for meeting layout
How I can hidden public_chat from meeting layout?
I am try solve that by using this steps:

commend: sudo bbb-conf --setuserdata userdata-bbb_show_public_chat_on_login=false
And I open this file /usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml
and search on this Layout parameter userdata-bbb_show_public_chat_on_login

But I can't find it.
How I can change value of this Layout parameter userdata-bbb_show_public_chat_on_login to false?
I am using BigBlueButton 2.7.
